# within in package function produces warning on lack of visible bindings

Tags: r, binding, scope, package, with-statement

Using `witin` inside a function in a package forces returns warning on `R CMD check`.

## reprex

The function:

```
# Test within

hello <- function(x = data.frame(valA = 1, valB = 2)) {
  within(data = x,
         expr = {
             res = valA + valB
         })
}
```

will produce the following warnings on `R CMD check`:

```
❯ checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
  hello: no visible binding for global variable ‘valA’
  hello: no visible binding for global variable ‘valB’
  Undefined global functions or variables:
    valA valB
```

## Workaround <strike>*(solution)*</strike>

Adding `valA <- valB <- NULL` will silence the warning.

```
hello <- function(x = data.frame(valA = 1, valB = 2)) {
    valA <- valB <- NULL

  within(data = x,
         expr = {
             res = valA + valB
         })
}
```

## Question

This shenanigans with `valA <- valB <- NULL` feels naff to me. What's the proper approach to handle this situation?

I want to use `within` as the function suits well wider function design. What's the proper way of silencing the warning. I came across [a similar discussion](https://github.com/STAT545-UBC/Discussion/issues/451) on GitHub that suggests using `with` in slightly different case.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to include `globalVariables(c('valA', 'valB'))` somewhere within the package, e.g. in a separate `.R` file within the `R` folder.

Otherwise I'd do:

```
hello <- function(valA = 1, valB = 2) {

  within(data = data.frame(valA, valB),
         expr = {
           res = valA + valB
         })
}
```

Comment: I know - it's a dirty hack, but unfortunately necessary as function-specific variables cannot exist if not defined as arguments in the context of CRAN checks ...